# How is this url configured?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I just bought a script online. On the home page (index.php) there's link

```
<a href="lookup.html">lookup</a>
```

Acturally, the page lookup.html does not exist. When you click the link, it still brings you to lookup.html, of which the content is run by lookup.php.

I don't any place where lookup.php is invoked.

I checked .htaccess file settings on the server (dreamhost). It seems nothing configured. How is this url configured? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally when frameworks like Drupal are installed they make a local .htaccess file.
Kindly check if there is a .htaccess file with rewrite engine enabled, where the script is installed.

Also besides the point, rewriting .php to html does not give any benefits on the SEO front.